# SonarQube: Coverage on New Code never calculated

Tags: maven, sonarqube, cobertura, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-scan

I have set up SonarQube, Maven and Cobertura to upload unit test coverage at every build run. I want to use the differential views to get coverage for the delta (new code only).

The coverage itself is successfully uploaded, and I can see the delta in lines of code. However, I can't get the "Coverage on new Code" to work.

I tried different values for the leak period, including `previous_analysis` and `previous_version` (changing the version from 1.0 to 1.1 in the new analysis). I also used `-Dsonar.projectDate` to simulate a past date of analysis but still no luck.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key requirement to obtain *new_code* -related information/metrics is to leverage [SonarQube SCM integration](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SCM+support). And to benefit from that you have to install a compatible SCM Plugin applicable to your project (e.g. [Git Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Git+Plugin), [SVN Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SVN+Plugin) etc.).

Comment: That's what I have in mind, but I wanted to create a minimum viable product "manually" first. So you're saying I can't use the `new_code` by manually uploading from the command-line?

Comment: I don't understand your question. All I'm saying is that you should install the [Git Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Git+Plugin) (or else depending on the SCM you're using) and verify that SCM integration is enabled in your project settings. That's because *New Code* is detected based on SCM *blame* information.

Comment: I installed the Jazz RTC plug-in and the results I'm seeing in SonarQube are the very same - I can see the new lines of code, but no new coverage :(

Comment: Interestingly, it's working with Git. I will accept your answer and send a separate question just for jazz. Thanks @Nicolas

Comment: I have added `sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2.jar` to `sonarqube-6.2/extensions/plugins/` since I'm using Git for scm. However, nothing changed. Is that enough?

Answer (score 1):

"Coverage on New Code" is only displayed if you are using/activating SCM support (SVN, Git, ...).

`sonar.scm.disabled=false`

Comment: What is it? What's that for, why we should disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this sonar.java.binaries=classes directory, most likely target/classes
helped me in fixing this issue. [No JaCoCo analysis of project coverage can be done since there is no class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399898/no-jacoco-analysis-of-project-coverage-can-be-done-since-there-is-no-class-files)

Comment: please consider adding relevant info from your link to the space provided in the answer.