# SonarQube 6.2 doesn't show coverage on new code

Tags: sonarqube

I want my project to fail if the code coverage on new code is not 70%.

Therefore, I set `Coverage on New Code` to 70% in `Quality Gates`.

I analyse code that has 84.1% coverage. Then I add some files which don't have test coverage and the coverage drops to 58%.

So obviously, the coverage on new code is not 70%.

Despite this, `Quality Gates` is `Passed` and `Coverage on New Code` is `-`

My project is in Scala, I'm using Maven as the build tool and Scoverage for test coverage.

Why doesn't SonarQube see the coverage on new code?

Comment: Where does Scoverage place the coverage results? Look at the log to find any lines regarding this file.

Comment: Before anything: see if [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237636/sonarqube-coverage-on-new-code-never-calculated) helps. If not then update your question with details on SCM plugin used and analysis logs.

Comment: @Nicolas I have added `sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2.jar` to `sonarqube-6.2/extensions/plugins/` since I'm using Git for scm. However, nothing changed. Is that enough?

Comment: Add/commit code with test coverage, then build/test and analyse with debug logs (_sonar.verbose=true_) to see if the SCM sensor does its jobs during analysis. Update your question with analysis logs if needed.

Comment: @Nicolas I've added the option `sonar.verbose=true`. I looked in the logs from `sonarqube-6.2/logs` but I didn't find any reference to `scoverage`. Any idea what I should be looking for?